# How risky is it to mail DVDs of pirated movies to other countries?

Tags: united-states, copyright, criminal-law, international, shipping

This is 100% hypothetical!

If somebody in the USA ships DVDs with pirated movies on them to some country overseas, for example the UK, could the recipient or the sender get into trouble by whoever it is that checks parcels?

Comment: You're not specifying the country of residence of the recipient, but in most cases, yes, both could get into trouble.

Comment: @jcaron I was asking about the USA.

Comment: Shipping to or from the US?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Shipping from.

Comment: @JoeMorano er, since you have now answered that the recipient is in the US, and that the shipping is *from* the US, there is no *other countries* part left... Could you please edit the question to make the countries clear?

Comment: @YviDe I'm sorry, I made it more clear now. It's being shipped from the US, to some overseas country.

Comment: As @jcaron kind of mentioned, it's going to depend on that country, too. You ask specifically whether the recipient could get into trouble, and that will depend on where they live.

Comment: @YviDe Let's say the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.gov.uk/duty-free-goods/banned-and-restricted-goods tells us:

> If you bring goods suspected of infringing intellectual property
>   rights (eg ‘pirate’ copies of movies or music) they may be seized and
>   you could be prosecuted.

Note that there is a lot of variation from one country to another in terms of enforcement of copyright and other IP. In some countries, this is solely a civil matter (i.e. only the rights holders can make a claim against you), while in others it is (also) a criminal matter (i.e. you can be fined and/or imprisoned). In others still, it is usually a civil matter, but there is criminal enforcement for some cases (for instance larger operations).

In the UK, customs are able to seize the suspected fraudulent goods and notify the rights holders, which can then decide to pursue the claim.

More details are available here: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/customs-seizures-and-penalties#protecting-intellectual-property-rights

Comment: Interesting. So say customs officials search a package and find some CD-ROMs. Do you have any idea how likely they would be to find them suspicious or actually check what's on them? Would that even be legal without a warrant?

Comment: In many countries, customs officers actually have a lot more rights than regular law enforcement officials. Not sure about the specifics in the UK.

Comment: If you had to guess, would you think they would find CD-ROMs suspicious?

Comment: They probably wouldn't bother for a single disc. It you send a box of 200 discs carefully labelled, that's another story. I would guess this is not their primary focus these days, but it's still part of their job.

Comment: In any case, since it **is** illegal, don't do it.

Comment: Absolutely, this is all hypothetical. I was just curious.